# Detect if a socket has a wrong IP and cannot connect

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am creating an application on Android that connects to a server on my PC via sockets. The application has a list of hosts and the user presses on the one he wants to connect to at the moment. The problem is, if he presses on a host that is not currently connected (i.e. the server-side program isn't running, or the machine is turned off), the application freezes. I detected that the app stays on this line of code `sck = new Socket(ip, 8081);` forever.

Is there any way to check if a machine can accept connections before creating the socket? Or generating an error from this? Or any way around it?

Thank you.

PS: `UnknownHostException` is only thrown when the IP is written in a wrong format, not if it is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I detected that the app stays on this line of code sck = new Socket(ip, 8081); forever.

No it doesn't. It blocks for the platform timeout, which is about a minute. If your application freezes it means you are doing this operation on a GUI thread instead of its own thread. You can shorten the timeout as follows:

```
Socket sck = new Socket();
sck.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), timeout);
```

where `timeout` is in milliseconds. Note that you can't increase it beyond the platform default, despite what it says in the Javadoc. Zero is not 'infinite' here, it is the platform default.

> Is there any way to check if a machine can accept connections before creating the socket?

You mean like foretelling the future? Fortune-telling? No.

> Or generating an error from this?

See above.

> Or any way around it?

See above.